# Cannot get Swiper JS to work on my WordPress theme, what's wrong?

Tags: wordpress, themes, swiper.js

I am new to WordPress theme development, I want to use Swiper JS for my sliders. Have tried all I could but is not working. Can someone please help me on how to set it up?

For the slider in my page was set up this way:

```
<php?


<div class="swiper tree">
 <div class="swiper-wrapper">
   <div class="swiper-slide slide_1">slide 1</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide slide_1">slide 2</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide slide_1">slide 1</div>
 </div>
</div>

?>
```

This is how I wrote the JavaScript in my main.js file, I then added it to my function.php:

```
<script>


var swiper = new Swiper(".slide", {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 54566,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
  breakpoints: {
    280: {
      slidesPerView: 1,
      spaceBetween: 10,
    },
    390: {
      slidesPerView: 1,
      spaceBetween: 10,
    },
    485: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 15,
    },
    510: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 10,
    },
    640: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 20,
    },
    768: {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 15,
    },
    1024: {
      slidesPerView: 4,
      spaceBetween: 20,
    },
  },
});


<script/>
```

I added the main.js file and Swiper css and Swiper js files:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){

      /** include style file */

      //styling ========================



        // adding swiper-bundle files
        wp_enqueue_style('swiper-bundle-css',get_template_directory_uri().'/place/css/swiper-bundle.min.css');

        // adding stylesheet
        wp_enqueue_style('custom-style',get_stylesheet_uri());

     //styling ========================


     //javascripts =======================
          // adding js file
          wp_enqueue_script('main-js',get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/main.js', [], '1.1',);

           // adding jquery file
           wp_enqueue_script('jquery',get_template_directory_uri().'/place/js/jquery-3.6.1.min.js');


            // adding swiper js file
            wp_enqueue_script('swiper-bundle-js',get_template_directory_uri().'/place/js/swiper-bundle.min.js', [],'8.4.2',);


});
```

Comment: What have you tried exactly? If you could share your non-working code here we may be able to tell you what the problem is (see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: Ok have added it

Comment: Are you using actual `<script>` tags inside your main.js file? Or was it a typo when you pasted your code here?

Comment: No just d swiper file

Comment: @Scotty Did you ever sort this out? I've noticed that the examples (say, `effects: cards`) do not have the `swiper-3d` class applied in the DOM to the target element at initialization under a Wordpress installation, but do in a simple test.

Answer (score 0):

In your initialization, you are currently targeting a `slide` class, which doesn't seem to exist.

Given that you gave your Swiper html structure the class `tree`, try using this to initialize Swiper instead:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".tree", {
    ...
}
```

If you ever have a doubt, it's always useful to refer back to [the documentation](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#initialize-swiper).

Comment: Have also tried it, didn't work. This is for a WordPress site I don't know why is not working